# Validation error while calling api with files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, jsx

I am using react, redux for backend and jsx for a project which requires taking image file as an input from the user and sending it to some api to upload it.
Here is my code:

function post(request) {

```
let config = request.server.app.config;
if (!imageEditClient) {
    imageEditClient = new HttpClient('imageEditClient', {
        timeout: 5000,
        connectionTimeout: 5000,
        baseUrl: `${config.get('api.baseUrl')}`
    });
}

request.log(['UploadImage payload coming from request'], request.payload);

let payload = request.payload;
let suffix = 'ImageUpload';
// let blob = new Blob([request.params.imageFile], {type: 'image/jpeg'});

let form = new FormData({maxDataSize: 20971520});

    let form = new FormData({maxDataSize: 20971520});

    const options = {
        payload,
        headers: {
            'If-Match': '*',
            'Content-Type': undefined

        }
    };

    form.append('file', request.params.imageFile);
    form.append('json', request.params.dataFile);

    return imageEditClient.post(suffix, options, form).then(mutate)
        .catch((err) => {
            err.message = `ImageEditService: ${err.message} - ${suffix}.`;
            throw err;
        });
```

}

I am getting the following error:

```
[1] "value" must be a Function
[HAPIJS]     at Object.exports.process (/Users/alnc/ha_projects/content-catalog-node-ui/node_modules/joi/lib/errors.js:181:19)
[HAPIJS]     at iterate (/Users/alnc/ha_projects/content-catalog-node-ui/node_modules/items/lib/index.js:36:13)
[HAPIJS] [2018-09-03 09:20:51,836](53611) [log] [warn] - shutting down.
[HAPIJS] Debug: internal, implementation, error 
[HAPIJS]     ValidationError: Uncaught error: {
[HAPIJS]   "_overheadLength": 206,
[HAPIJS]   "_valueLength": 26,
[HAPIJS]   "_valuesToMeasure": [],
[HAPIJS]   "writable": false,
[HAPIJS]   "readable": true,
[HAPIJS]   "dataSize": 0,
[HAPIJS]   "maxDataSize": 20971520,
[HAPIJS]   "pauseStreams": true,
[HAPIJS]   "_released": false,
[HAPIJS]   "_streams": [
[HAPIJS]     "----------------------------703740497184449347716405\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"\r\n\r\n",
[HAPIJS]     "[object Blob]",
[HAPIJS]     function () { [native code] },
[HAPIJS]     "----------------------------703740497184449347716405\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"json\"\r\n\r\n",
[HAPIJS]     "[object Blob]",
[HAPIJS]     function () { [native code] }
[HAPIJS]   ],
[HAPIJS]   "_currentStream": null,
[HAPIJS]   "_boundary": "--------------------------703740497184449347716405",
[HAPIJS]   "value" [1]: -- missing --
[HAPIJS] }
```

The error is not clear to me.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

you can not use a form data from react like this, you should first process your imageFile and make e Blob object out of the requested image then send the image's blob object that you just created to the form data object (append this Blob to your 'file' property of the form data instead of appending the image of the request directly), these functions can help you do the converting to blob job for your images:

```
      function dataURLtoBlob(dataURL) {
        const binary = atob(dataURL.split(',')[1]);
        const array = [];
        const length = binary.length;
        let i;
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
        }
        return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)]);
      }
```

the next two functions are to create an image from your inputed image and get a dataUrl out of file reader for it in order to use it in the above function for the converting to blob process, the first function is the main function that gets called from where you input the image from user:

```
      export function processFile(file) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          try {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            reader.onloadend = async function() {
              const processedFile = await handleImage(reader.result);
              resolve(processedFile);
            };
          } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
          }
        });
      }
```

then:

```
      async function handleImage(dataURL) {
        const image = new Image();
        image.src = dataURL;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          image.onload = function() {
              resolve(dataURLtoBlob(dataURL, fileType));
          };
          image.onerror = reject;
        });
      }
```

for the rest of your code if you are getting images from input you can use event.target.files[0] from the event attached to your file input change to send it as the file variable in the function processFile above and then append it to your form data:
first:

```
  imageData = await processFile(fileData);
```

and then from your code of form data:

```
  form.append('file', imageData);
```

Comment: Hi Mehrnaz, thanks for the quick response.
The imageFile is already converted to blob on client-side.
let blob = new Blob([imageFile], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
Isn't this the right way to do this?